# Lollipop Bad WiFi connection and Fallback to Mobile Network, how to Detect?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

Lollipop has a new feature which is causing a huge problem for me.  The system will fall back, transparently, to Mobile data when the WiFi network is "connected" but has no internet. 
http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/18/lollipop-feature-spotlight-android-now-defaults-to-mobile-data-when-wi-fi-has-no-internet-access-signal-icon-adds-a-for-no-connection/

Since one of the apps I make for my company is a WiFi testing application, similar to Fing etc, this is causing issues in Lollipop.  I NEED to send packets out on the bad WiFi signal, so that problems can be located and fixed, ex Traceroute, Ping etc.  While external IP's may not work, internal IP addresses should still be reachable in a scenario like this.   However with the connection automatically falling back to the mobile network this is not longer possible.

I have not yet found any solution to detecting this.  `NetworkInfo.getState()` and `NetworkInfo.getDetailedState()` both report "DISCONNECTED" even though the WiFi is connected and just has a bad external connection.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  All research thus far has led me to believe I can't force packets over the WiFi connection in Android, and I haven't figured out if I can detect this state.  Other than detecting if Mobile data is on, and asking the user to turn it off, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request a specific connection type (or a specific network) using [`ConnectivityManager#requestNetwork()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestNetwork%28android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback%29).

You can then use a [`NetworkRequest.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.Builder.html) to request a WiFi network like so:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = 
        (ConnectivityManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .build();

cm.requestNetwork(request,
                  new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                      void onAvailable(Network network) {
                         // Do something once the network is available
                      }
                  });
```

The builder also allows you to specify additonal constraints (called "capabilities"), so you can optionally speficy more requirements such as a specific SSID.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the NetworkRequest.Builder and hadn't seen it mentioned.  This is awesome, let me see what I can accomplish, I will mark this if I can get it to work.

Comment: So does only the code in the onAvailable callback run through the Wifi network, or once you have requested a wifi transport, can you make this affect the entire app?

Comment: Once you have the `Network` you want, you can call [`ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) to use that network for all calls from your process.

Comment: Was there a way to do something similar to this Pre-Lollipop? I had been relying on the fact that if you were connected to WiFi, but had a bad connection, the phone would still send out packets over WiFi... Or is it safe to make that assumption pre-lollipop and just not worry about it.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there is no way to do this pre-lollipop. I believe Android will just keep happily sending packets to a WiFi network with no internet connection.

Comment: I got this implemented today and successfully get an onAvailable call back even though the WiFi has no external internet, at which point I call `ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork(network)`.  I bet this is working as expected, however.. and I REALLY hope I can get around this, since my TraceRoute function and Ping function spin up command line processes, and read the OutputBuffer, these processes are now separate system level processes with their own process ID, and are are not affected by my `setProcessDefaultNetwork` and complete successfully using mobile data. Any way around this?

Comment: But do you get onAvailable event when mobile data internet is working okey? Testing this on Nexus5 5.0.1 and event is not triggered. What I'm getting of all events when wifi is activated and set up is event onLinkPropertiesChanged